# JavaScript form validation: Why does the first work but the second doesn't?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form action="next.html" id="userInput" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
     Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>


function validate() {
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

            if(age > 100 || age < 0) {

                alert("Age must be within 0 and 100");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

This works as normal. If I enter a number in the age textbox great than 100, it will show the error message and stay at the current form page.

However, if I use a variable errorMessage as the following to show the alert box, it doesn't work. It will go to the next page without poping up the alert error message.

```
function validate() {
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

            var errorMessage="";
            if(age > 100 || age < 0) {
                errorMessage = "Age must be within 0 and 100";
            }


            if( errorMessage !== "" )
                alert(errorMessage);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

So why does the first work but the second doesn't?

Comment: I'm surprised the first one works, since the value of a text element is... text, and a numeric comparison shouldn't be meaningful.

Comment: Yes, it works in Firefox and Chrome :)

Comment: Oh, right; it'll automatically convert, sorry. You should make a jsfiddle or equivalent for people to test easily.

Comment: Did you try if( errorMessage != "" ) instead of if( errorMessage !== "" )

Comment: Please keep your browser's console open so you can see the `SyntaxError`, and use a validator if you need help tracking it down. http://jshint.com

Comment: surely the second example needs an opening { for the if/else block.

Comment: @MeyerDenney: I tried using != but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @MeyerDenney: It's a string to string comparison, so type coercion wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @the system, I didn't mention anything about type coercion.  I mentioned the missing brace.

Comment: @MikeHogan: Sorry, I sent the notification to the wrong user. Fixed.

Comment: @MikeHogan; Thanks a lot. Problem solved. It is the open { problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my IDE doesn't prompt me for any missing pair of {}.

Comment: @tonga: Doesn't matter. Your browser's console would tell you. Make sure your browser's developer tools are open when testing your site.

Comment: @thesystem: Thanks for your reminding. I should have used that for debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a missing left brace after the condition. The code should be:

```
    if( errorMessage !== "" ){
        alert(errorMessage);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I noticed the same thing when I copied the code to jsfiddle and clicked on "Tidy Up".

Answer (score 3):

```
function validate() {
        var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value),
        errorMessage;

        if(age > 100 || age < 0) errorMessage = "Age must be within 0 and 100";
        if(errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage);
            return false;
        } 
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I shortened it a bit, but your main problem was not having a bracket after if(errorMessage != "") :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is syntax as the others have pointed out... you are missing the { after the if statement. You may want to consider copying future code and pasting it into an online javascript syntax checker. E.g. http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php